# .fadeToggle() makes my sub list unaccessable

Tags: jquery, html

I' nesting lists within a list, and I'm trying to toggle the sub-lists when the user clicks the respective topic. However, what happens is that the user can click anywhere on the sub-list to close the sub-list, which will make the the links inaccessible. (I know there are not links in the sub-lists now).
Can you help me solve this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list li").click(function() {
    $(this).find("ul").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      TOPIC I
      <ul class="inner-lists">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This works better than trying to stopPropagation (see next snippet for explanation):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list span").click(function(e) {
    $(this).next("ul").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      <span>TOPIC I</span>
      <ul class="inner-lists">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```

In your code you needed to stop the propagation, but that did not stop the click between the child LIs from closing too. Try to click between line 1 and 2 in the sublist here to see what I mean

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("ul").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      TOPIC I
      <ul class="inner-lists">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: stoppropagation. But it did not fully work when clicking the cracks between the LIs in the sub list. I have fixed that now

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you can call `stopPropagation()` in the click handler. This will stop the event bubbling up the DOM to the parent `li` and fading the `ul`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#list li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find("ul").fadeToggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>
      TOPIC I
      <ul class="inner-lists">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="display"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still closes if you click between the LIs in the inner list